# shell script : remove first column from txt files

Tags: macos, shell

Hy everyone,

I would like to remove the first column from a  lot of .txt files stored in a folder.

So far I've tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash
#  loop on all .txt files
for i in $(ls *.txt); do
#  remove first column
  cut -d' ' -f2- < $i
#  remove temporary file
  rm $i.bak
done
exit
```

This only print the result of the cut in the shell window, but it doesn't modify the files. I missing something really easy here but I can't figure out where I should indicate that I want to write the result of the cut.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what @anishsane means to say is: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Err, yes. forgot to give link..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu # stop on error
#  loop on all .txt files
for i in *.txt; do
#  remove first column
  cut -d' ' -f2- < $i > $i.new
#  replace old file
  mv $i.new $i
done
```

Comment: maybe: `cut -d' ' -f2- < "$i" > "$i.new"  &&  mv "$i.new" "$i"` for some level of safety :)

Comment: @jm666: thanks for the reminder; I did one better and made the script stop on any error with "set -eu".

Answer (score 3):

Redirect `STDOUT` to `$i.bak`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- < $i > $i.bak
mv $i.bak $i
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `awk` approach to printing everything but the first column:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

You can set the field separator with `FS=` - it defaults to a white space.

Use loop control as per normal, *e.g*. here's how to remove the UID and GID columns from a collection of `passwd` files (stored as `passwd-hostid_number` *i.e.* `passwd-01` ... `passwd-99`):

```
for pwdfile in passwd[0-9][0-9] ; 
 do 
 awk 'FS=":", OFS=":" {$3=""; $4=""; print $0}' $pwdfile > $pwdfile-no-uidgid
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to edit your files in place using sed:

```
sed -i -e 's/^[^ ]* //' *.txt
```

This will remove any non whitespace chars including the first whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Open in vi editor and in command mode (Press Esc), type

```
:%! awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

and press enter and save.